# Inserting Data into Many to many table Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony1

I am trying to insert data into a database table using a `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoiceMany` Symfony widget. For some unknown reason the data will insert if 2 values are selected from each field, but will not if 3 are selected in one field and only 1 or 2 in the other, like so :

[image]

However I get an error when I try to do this:

[image]

I am using Doctrine to generate my tables in the database. This is my schema:

```
#Article tables

SteerCmsArticle:
  columns:
    title:                 string(255)
    content:               string
    file:                  string(255)
    date_created:          string(255)
    active:                boolean
  relations:
    Tags:
      class:                SteerCmsArticleTags
      local:                a_id
      foreign:              a_tag_id
      refClass:             SteerCmsTaggedArticles
    Categories:
      class:                SteerCmsArticleCat
      local:                a_id
      foreign:              a_cat_id
      refClass:             SteerCmsCategorisedArticles

SteerCmsArticleCat:
  columns:
    name:             string(255)

SteerCmsArticleTags:
  columns:
    name:             string(255)

SteerCmsTaggedArticles:
  columns:
    a_id:                   integer(20)
    a_tag_id:               integer(20)
  relations:
    SteerCmsArticle:
      onDelete:               CASCADE
      local:                  a_id
      foreign:                id
    SteerCmsArticleTags:
      onDelete:               CASCADE
      local:                  a_tag_id
      foreign:                id

SteerCmsCategorisedArticles:
  columns:
    a_id:                   integer(20)
    a_cat_id:               integer(20)
  relations:
    SteerCmsArticle:
      onDelete:               CASCADE
      local:                  a_id
      foreign:                id
    SteerCmsArticleCat:
      onDelete:               CASCADE
      local:                  a_cat_id
      foreign:                id
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant believe how silly I am was literally about to rebuild my model from scratch a simple spelling mistake when generating the form and validators. Make sure your validators correspond correctly with the forms triple check spelling!

```
'categories_list'      => new sfValidatorDoctrineChoiceMany(array('model' => 'SteerCmsArticle**Tags**', 'required' => false)),
```

Was ment to be...

```
'categories_list'      => new sfValidatorDoctrineChoiceMany(array('model' => 'SteerCmsArticle**Cats**, 'required' => false)),
```